# Prime factor of $2 \uparrow \uparrow 4 + 3\uparrow \uparrow 4$

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, tetration

I checked the prime factors of

$$2 \uparrow \uparrow 4 + 3\uparrow \uparrow 4 = 2^{2^{2^2}} + 3^{3^{3^3}}$$

with trial division and found non below $8*10^9$

Nevertheless, the given number has still a very low chance to be prime.
Can anything be said about the possible prime factors ? The only restriction
I found is that -3 must be a quadratic residue for any prime factor.

You can join in searching for a prime factor at github :

https://github.com/gnufinder/prime-factor

Comment: "the given number has a very low probability to be prime". What could this possibly mean? What is the probability of 17 being a prime? What is the probability of 685?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Well, for primality tests we have the notion of "probable prime", so I assume that "very low probability to be prime" is saying that it's "probably composite" in a similar sense.

Comment: @DennisMeng Those notions are test dependent, while no such test is specified here. (I suppose one could use Cebotarev's theorem to extract something from the fact about $-3$.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo True. I guess I just kind of assumed that was where he was coming from (and assumed he didn't explicitly say so because it wasn't essential to the actual question)

Comment: If someone hates the word "probable" concerning primes (with the reason that it is determined whether a number is prime or not), I can formulate it in a different way : Because of the enormous magnitude I am convinced that the number is composite.

Comment: ...I'm *pretty* sure that the primes don't get less dense when you look through bigger and bigger numbers, but I'd have to do a little digging.

Comment: These are really big numbers; both (3^^4+2^^4) and (15^^3+14^^3) are bigger then the biggest known prime, the Mersenne prime 2^57885161. I'm learning about prime testing and implemented the "right to left binary method" in the Wikipedia article on Modular exponentiation; Fermat's little theorem, 2x speedup for 15^^3+14^^3. Factoring 2^^4+3^^4, so far factoring primes up to 5.9E9 by trial division, with no prime factors found. I also tried it on Mersenne "like" primes, and some of them near the largest have largest Meresene number have prime factors>1E7, like 2^57885109-1. Interesting topic....

Comment: I think the prime probability for a large random number is 1/ln(x), which is less than 10^-12 for random numbers of magnitude 3^^4.  So I agree, "the given number has still a very low probability to be prime".  But I think the probability for a composite with prime factors > 10^10 is very much larger, perhaps as large as 1/50 or so but that is merely an intuitive guess, using the prime density for 10^20.  If that is approximately correct, one would expect many escapes using trial division to 10^10.

Comment: @Sheldon Long ago, I read in a publication that the probability, that a number has no prime factors below p, is asymptotically $\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{ln(p)}$. For $10^{10}$ , this would approximately be $\frac{1}{41}$. So, the probability of a very large number to be prime only multiplies with about 41. So my number still is "very probably composite".

Comment: I figured out that this formula for the number of primes below p, is exp(-incomplete_gamma)/ln(p).  I haven't used the incomplete gamma before.  Can you show me how to evaluate it for 10^10? Also, verified no prime factors below 2*E10, for (3^4+2^4), and below 1E10, for (15^^3+14^^3).  Assuming this equation for primes acts as I think it would, then if we factor to 10^20, or p^2, the probability would only be cut in half, and if we went to 10^80, there would still be a 1/8th of a chance of not finding smallest prime factor, so this problem is not solvable for a large bucket of these numbers.

Comment: 2^^5+3^^5 is divisible by 34276387

Comment: @Peter, "if the number IS prime, it is hopeless to prove it," I would have said it is hopeless to find a prime factor, but I'm not sure about prime testing, isn't prime testing usually easier?.  I'm sure the reasonable upper bounds on factoring is 10^80, probably lower without a huge farm of computers, and perhaps much lower since none of the advanced techniques work on numbers of this size.

Comment: Perhaps, I underestimated today's possibilities. If 10^12-digit numbers can be handled already, there is a chance to show that a number with magnitude 10^10^12 (like mine) is probable prime. Prime proving is nearly hopeless, but the probability could be made so high, that there would be no doubt. Finding a factor (if there is a "small") is far easier than doing such a primality test. Factorizations are more difficult, but 120 digit-numbers can be factored today with a single normal computer in a few days, with many computers, 200-digit-numbers can be factored,too.

Comment: The primality test for my number would take a very long time, but if you want, replace "hopeless" with "very difficult and time-consuming"

Comment: How about the smallest prime factor for (2^^6 + 3^^6)?

Comment: ok, I said I have two working algorithms; they both seem to agree.  They both say that (2^^5+3^^5)mod 34276387 = (2^^6+3^^6)mod 34276387.  I didn't use these to verify that this is the smallest factor.  Slow algorithm took ~4 minutes, but finds the shortest repeating chain, and seems theoretically "correct".  Fast algorithm took ~1 millisecond; but I'm less certain of boundary conditions.  So far, both agree.  For smaller values of n, the slow algorithm works ok, with time proportional to n or perhaps a little bigger since its multiplication.  Could post as answer to your "a^n mod m" question?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/319713/can-i-find-the-remainder-more-efficiently/319715?noredirect=1#comment678647_319715

Comment: @SheldonL It is not hard to show that the sequence $a\uparrow\uparrow n \pmod m$ is eventually constant (in $n$) for any fixed base $a$ and modulus $m$.  The fifth iterate of Carmichael lambda on $34276387$ is very small ($\lambda^{\circ 5}(34276387) = 2$), so chances are that $2\uparrow\uparrow + 3\uparrow\uparrow n$ is also divisible by $34276387$ for every $n \ge 5$.

Comment: I don't understand whether you tried any primality test...

Comment: @Peter: I've checked in GAP up to $2*10^{10}$ using the code that I've submitted to you in my pull request https://github.com/gnufinder/prime-factor/pull/5. The code is just refactoring of your previous attempt in GAP. No prime factors were found. Runtime is perhaps an overnight calculation (had to restart it a couple of times because of memory problems). Still this is hopeless to continue as it is, since this number has  $3,638,334,640,025$ digits - this is $162872$ times more than the largest known prime which has $22,338,618$ digits.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thank you for verifying! We do not know whether it is hopeless to continue. If there is no "small" prime factor, yes, then it is hopeless. But perhaps, there is a prime factor in the range [$2\cdot 10^{10},10^{12}$]. Or in the range [$10^{12},10^{13}$] , or ...

Comment: @MichaelChapman A primility test is probably out of reach for such large numbers.

Comment: @Peter ok, perhaps we can chat about in in the next several days...

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov According to my self-written program, the cubefree-package returns the same values upto $50000$ as the NrSmallGroups-command. The calculation took about $3$ hours. I also cross-checked the squarefree-case of the NrSmallGroup-command with the formula I programmed in PARI/GP. The checksum for the values upto $10^7$ coincided, so everything seems alright. It remains to verify the $pq^2$-case.

Comment: @Peter excellent - I suggest just to submit one issue in which you will describe this.

Comment: This number is almost 10000 digits.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Which number do you mean ? The number given in the question is much, much bigger.

Comment: $3^{3^{3^3}}=3^{3^9}=3^{19683}<10^{10000}$. So this question was $8*10^9$ , but if $10^{100}$, prime check is ok.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki The power tower is $$\large 3^{3^{3^3}}=3^{3^{27}}=3^{7625597484987}>>10^{10000}$$

Comment: And trial division upto $10^{100}$ would not be sufficient to check whether a number with magnitude $10^{10000}$ is prime, the square root would be $10^{5000}$

Comment: Ah, I got it. It seem I didn't correctly calculate from that time.