# Smallest Strong Pseudoprime for any finite set of bases

Tags: number-theory

Is there any (simple) method I could use to find the smallest strong pseudoprime between any finite set of bases $a, b, c$...

> For example, I am trying to find the smallest strong pseduoprime in both bases $17$ and $31$. The way I would start doing that is by taking the $\gcd(17^n-1, 31^n-1)$, and cheking divisors of $\gcd(17^n-1, 31^n-1)$ to see if they are strong pseudoprimes to bases $17$ and $31$. Is there any faster method? If so, can someone please show me the smallest such strong pseduoprime (for bases $17$ and $31$.) and how it was found?

Also, is there an upper bound (approximation) for the smallest strong pseudoprime for any finite set of bases?

Comment: I do not think that we have anything better than brute force.

Comment: A simple loop over the non-primes shows that $4033$ is the smallest number which is strong pseudoprime for bases $17,31.$

A more mathematical strategy might be found in some links from the reference section at
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime (but I did not check this).

Comment: Brute force takes too long... even finding a base-359 pseduoprime would be too hard? Would anyone know a shortcut to finding one?

Comment: Huh? Do you mean brute force without computer? :) The times for $4033$ and that $9$ is the smallest strong pseudoprime to base $359$ are 1ms on my old Core-2 Duo (I guess, it is actually faster because this is the smallest displayable time scale). For the case 9 this is just the third number to test $(4,6,9)$. And as Peter commented, there seems to be no shortcut.

Comment: I am looking for two bases, $a$ and $b$ such that the smallest strong pseudoprime to both is greater than $2^{64}$.

Comment: This : http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/ should be helpful. Probably, $2$ bases do not suffice to get to $2^{64}$.

Comment: @gammatester you seem to have a powerful powermod-function. Maybe you can help me with this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625576/prime-factor-of-2-uparrow-uparrow-4-3-uparrow-uparrow-4

Answer (score 0):

Here's my algorithm for generating the smallest squarefree strong pseudoprime to a given list of bases:

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 4344 bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Daniel "Trizen" Șuteu
# Date: 23 December 2023
# https://github.com/trizen

# Generate all the squarefree k-omega strong Fermat pseudoprimes in range [A,B] to multiple given bases. (not in sorted order)

# See also:
#   https://trizenx.blogspot.com/2020/08/pseudoprimes-construction-methods-and.html

use 5.020;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::GMPz;
use ntheory qw(:all);
use experimental qw(signatures);

sub k_squarefree_strong_fermat_pseudoprimes_in_range ($A, $B, $k, $bases, $callback) {

    $A = vecmax($A, pn_primorial($k));

    my @bases     = @$bases;
    my $bases_lcm = lcm(@bases);

    $A = Math::GMPz-&gt;new("$A");
    $B = Math::GMPz-&gt;new("$B");

    my $u = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_init();
my $v = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_init();

    my $generator = sub ($m, $L, $lo, $k) {

        Math::GMPz::Rmpz_tdiv_q($u, $B, $m);
    Math::GMPz::Rmpz_root($u, $u, $k);

        my $hi = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_get_ui($u);

        if ($lo &gt; $hi) {
            return;
        }

        if ($k == 1) {

            Math::GMPz::Rmpz_cdiv_q($u, $A, $m);

            if (Math::GMPz::Rmpz_fits_ulong_p($u)) {
            $lo = vecmax($lo, Math::GMPz::Rmpz_get_ui($u));
        }
        elsif (Math::GMPz::Rmpz_cmp_ui($u, $lo) &gt; 0) {
            if (Math::GMPz::Rmpz_cmp_ui($u, $hi) &gt; 0) {
                return;
            }
            $lo = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_get_ui($u);
            }

            if ($lo &gt; $hi) {
                return;
            }

            Math::GMPz::Rmpz_invert($v, $m, $L);

            if (Math::GMPz::Rmpz_cmp_ui($v, $hi) &gt; 0) {
                return;
            }

            if (Math::GMPz::Rmpz_fits_ulong_p($L)) {
            $L = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_get_ui($L);
            }

            my $t = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_get_ui($v);
            $t &gt; $hi &amp;&amp; return;
            $t += $L while ($t &lt; $lo);

            for (my $p = $t ; $p &lt;= $hi ; $p += $L) {

                is_prime($p) || next;
            $bases_lcm % $p == 0 and next;

                Math::GMPz::Rmpz_mul_ui($v, $m, $p);
            Math::GMPz::Rmpz_sub_ui($u, $v, 1);
            if (vecall { is_strong_pseudoprime($v, $_) } @bases) {
                $callback-&gt;(Math::GMPz::Rmpz_init_set($v));
                }
            }

            return;
        }

        my $t   = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_init();
    my $lcm = Math::GMPz::Rmpz_init();

        foreach my $p (@{primes($lo, $hi)}) {

            $bases_lcm % $p == 0 and next;

            my $z = lcm(map { znorder($_, $p) } @bases);
        Math::GMPz::Rmpz_gcd_ui($Math::GMPz::NULL, $m, $z) == 1 or next;
            Math::GMPz::Rmpz_lcm_ui($lcm, $L, $z);
        Math::GMPz::Rmpz_mul_ui($t, $m, $p);

            __SUB__-&gt;($t, $lcm, $p + 1, $k - 1);
        }
    };

    $generator-&gt;(Math::GMPz-&gt;new(1), Math::GMPz-&gt;new(1), 2, $k);
}

sub squarefree_strong_fermat_pseudoprimes_in_range ($from, $upto, $bases) {

    my @arr;

    for (my $k = 2 ; ; ++$k) {
        last if pn_primorial($k) &gt; $upto;
        k_squarefree_strong_fermat_pseudoprimes_in_range($from, $upto, $k, $bases, sub ($n) { push @arr, $n });
    }

    @arr = sort { $a &lt;=&gt; $b } @arr;
    return @arr;
}

my @bases = (17, 31);

my $lo = Math::GMPz-&gt;new(2);
my $hi = 2 * $lo;

say ":: Searching for the smallest strong pseudoprime to bases: (@bases)";

while (1) {

    say ":: Sieving range: [$lo, $hi]";
    my @arr = squarefree_strong_fermat_pseudoprimes_in_range($lo, $hi, \@bases);

    if (@arr) {
        say "\nFound: $arr[0]";
        say "All terms: @arr\n" if (@arr &gt; 1);
        last;
    }

    $lo = $hi + 1;
    $hi = 2 * $lo;
}

__END__
:: Searching for the smallest strong pseudoprime to bases: (17 31)
:: Sieving range: [2, 4]
:: Sieving range: [5, 10]
:: Sieving range: [11, 22]
:: Sieving range: [23, 46]
:: Sieving range: [47, 94]
:: Sieving range: [95, 190]
:: Sieving range: [191, 382]
:: Sieving range: [383, 766]
:: Sieving range: [767, 1534]
:: Sieving range: [1535, 3070]
:: Sieving range: [3071, 6142]
:: Sieving range: [6143, 12286]
:: Sieving range: [12287, 24574]
:: Sieving range: [24575, 49150]
:: Sieving range: [49151, 98302]
:: Sieving range: [98303, 196606]
:: Sieving range: [196607, 393214]

Found: 197209
All terms: 197209 269011

perl script.pl  0.19s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 0.205 total
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVjbctpIEH3nK3oJSUkbA5IwYCCkYlc2eXFSW5vNU5JSCTEGlXXLzAjbJPzHftL@lbd7RoCAMY5rqZIR6tuZ090zLeeMx937@2e/tQvB25Mobef4pFZ7Bm@DNGIx1P/m0ZKldfj3n0KyQgkkG4LXgbcsZMmEcfAcr4OCuZS5GLbbs0jOi0krzJK2VMbk7j1LGUdLCOIY5JyB@F4EnF1xxuC6mSVsFoCQPEtn8I7xJJCQC1ZMs5xHCRMQpcCDdMbgy/nJxTeQGSRFLKM8ZjCLFiyFSSCYaIGVZpKURcYlm0LGp4zbFP8To9AiG@I9bKBqfLetSZzNRJ5JBRqX47Sds3YVQDPMUoRXhDLK0mbC5DybimaQTltzmSBfhWDQbaHhSN2iahRKfX8T8DRKZ2KktT4Ecj4cvv/w51KLUyQj43fw/cYaIje2fspuMQ8YOJVBTCIRzdJAFpwJVKiJYgLX/pZBXzPnXynm/CpwP0p9zZzVOD@BxgVe13gpvvA7xJiTILy24UethsxA4xzGsGBhEtwqizz1yVPGoyC2Gtc2xSe95A7eKCf0A03eaJejtVD/9OMwQSH@tbT22lyF2XLRfJ2yG6veOK/b2kPjwii/qFfiN4odneHwryRf4oIjadlbHItjShutma7PjKM20Ws1EmTnEq84I8o2/NDnwJ2cRgv/u9UoSoaTMr5RmWeZ1KqF8jzaOiYk88gEeMakX0RoVlWPrhBnnMFrsiKEUPlwhvWSbnGs9uyuYTwGd2ddRrhhZW3n5dp2LMjbgdVVJIVfxFSVOaHeR6dyjNC3tUY8H1l2hVG9muovFgsjijDJtbnKo41EOSYgj9oSuw/Ymqg2g9wu@Wh2dx0cMP1gvh8Csnokv1G6YBwLckG5pZr/pfyu2VkcZ@cXAP1C@Vyay@fyGJWXx6mkTpPH7Bd79qitaIcXL4yrQvnLMWG6mUcx7bYSXqmi22PzCrcYi6LnGB2VRnT3aqxcq3vl5aAtFVNCbcXMauQ2/PwJKbuVh0VX2XifqyhjcABPqlL9QP@AATxZN6mlgsjt0eNGuGduugUNXYMNJRqbnQaAH7SW8tCqnFY6pm/DqjxbHmq4zbHVfG0Z93ZfMCpp236sKffK4simqSsGHjty1qr64Dt@8JT1wIJwDrokrDc/9Lmt90NqrdVBLTwlw@R2WZ7ASZAj88tUTUVWw1e53XI9Or5PzMKpynBV8PHz5WVZJUtbnSc4chnq8sAZwlHO8Ls8ZpePxV@XpayU5Y6F73/6fOH7WBJKR7vGfgKXjllo7hSlroLVehrZHP87BaWnDtc@AdMzrzy9V3oge/I4dsUzQljkMlsPZJtU03QVcF7C2@wZeGaDh9vECF6@1DPJej1xICR12P64RpsWRdiu/KmD4z7QyvSoB6UUcUBeiLmCjNIUViXTZfvQc5qrcChH1UaA@x3CmlDpqUVuO698gHbb@XIMlts/gQ6lr6ZaKzPMhh5KN@OTB7@TGo3KwR3Uh0Oc/wMeznEOV2SqF5AE9xCGrJWvHZXF0/uFij2E9dhaR1/lzr6dmTbOI7Yg14qvIXxZ9@63@qiaTaLgidSXjk7g6@74THspuayWgELzNX2XFel0iCxz/sVZI9jIz@n1C0Pi0sj@K77ZrX1hqVQ7hCpqJ4uadyIYW6qc0nfZRkXf/@PjW9@v/R/K3T4lu2YgFlvu9JtJ0MUjxzFKXOx@zzOKvA666xlFp1hwA3OoAcUaPBBsgNE6Z@ZwnTOM1@@ZA/Z7GNHtdswxUYBRO07fHBYFGLfnnpoDowAju553Zo5NEozunXb75vAkwfinA7drBkASRDA46zhmCCQhDINez3kABImozQcdz0UYtbKO3UHfcwa1St3qJ@D1Bo7r1mr0DwsQIY9y2cpjAKflDgTgSzTHW8cVIO6EZAmCew5hXuBDz@liueGbde3@/j8)